# Mesh is Weirdly Deformed in Object & Sculpt Modes

Tags: objects, sculpting

I'm following a video tutorial on sculpting and when I switch back to object mode to review my work there are weird random spikes jutting out from my mesh, as best as I can determine they arise from attempting to work around the neck area.

[image: a help1]

Attempting the smooth or polish tool around the neckline causes this:
[image: a help2]

Here's edit mode.
[image: a editmode]

Here's sculpt mode:
[image: a sculpt]

In sculpt mode the original deformations didn't appear, I only noticed when I went to object mode. Back in sculpt mode the neckline deformations occured and all attempts to smooth it out haven't fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen results like this after adding new geometry to an object with a multires modifier. It seems having flipped normals contributes to this.

As your learning, I suggest you delete the multires, go into edit mode and select all vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to re-calculate the normals, add a new multires modifier then re-sculpt.

If you want to keep your sculpt data the only fix I can come up with is to apply the multires, go into edit mode, select the stray vertices and use smooth to bring them back into place. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select smooth or find Smooth Vertex in the spacebar menu, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to keep repeating the last step.

I think I found a way to reliably re-create the issue so will report a bug.

Comment: Please post a link to the bug report when you do it.

Comment: So far based on a suggestion from blender artists I think it had to do with two issues, but I haven't confirmed yet. One suggestion was to close the neck area and then use smoothing; this did appear to prevent the worst of the spikes that went out to the middle of nowhere but didn't prevent the smaller tinnier triangles that congregate at the neckline itself that you can see in picture 2. My assumption now is that when I extruded the new geometries to make the neck I didn't use the mouse but the arrow keys, perhaps it doesn't like sharp angles as a base?

Comment: [Bug reported](https://developer.blender.org/T42028)

Comment: To also reiterate, I never added new geometries to my mesh, I made the mesh as seen in figure 2 first and then added a multires modifier and then sculpted. Nothing else.

Comment: If you set the multires preview to 3 to match the sculpt does object and sculpt mode look more alike? Any chance you have duplicate vertices, in edit mode select all then W->Remove Doubles. You'll get a message at the top saying how many get removed. If your issue isn't the same cause as I describe I still think it's a bug, trouble is can we find a way to re-create the issue, or can your file provide enough info to find the bug?